# How to generate an AWS EC2 AMI to use with the vagrant-aws plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I'm trying to use the vagrant-aws plugin to create AWS EC2 instance. In [vagrant-aws documentation](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) it shows in the `Vagrantfile` the following line:

```
aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"
```

I have an existing `.box` file. How to generate an AMI?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

A `.box` file is a compressed version of your providers files (likely Virtualbox with vmdk, etc).

An AMI is an amazon specific format that does not have files you can hold or maintain.

This is apples to oranges. Your best bet is to find a base AMI from Amazon marketplace that matches your Box (CentOS 6.4, Ubuntu 14.07, etc) and make the changes you need to work with Vagrant.

Such changes (for centos) that I know of (after you launch a similar AMI from the marketplace and ssh into it):

1. `sed -i.bak "s/Defaults\s\+requiretty/Defaults !requiretty/g" /etc/sudoers`
2. `shred /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Create an AMI of this, and use that as your base AMI for Vagrant.